# SSM User does not have access to System Environment Variables

Tags: windows, powershell, environment-variables, aws-ssm

I am using Windows 10 on the servers where we run a .NET application, I need the machines to have environment variables to run a script that call those variables. I used this command as Administrator:
`[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("MYVARYABLE", "variable_value", [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)`

And it was added to the System Variables when I RDP into the Windows Machine and I can run the script that has a reference to `$env:MYVARYABLE`, I updated the environment using chocolatey `refreshenv`.

However, when I connect to the Instance using SSM (AWS Systems Manager), I don't longer have access to the environment variables, even though they are set as System Environment Variables.

I want to know why and what would be the best option to run that script from SSM Run Command, or when I connect to the Instance.

---

UPDATE

When I `reboot` the Instance from AWS, it has access now to the System Variables on the `SSM User`, I thought chocolatey `refreshenv` would do the work but it did not apparently, is there any way I can refresh those variables to be available without the need of restarting the machine?